# Multiple Apache vhost pointing to same directory

Tags: php, virtualhost

I have different domains, and related multiple Apache vhosts, pointing to the same directory.
So, basically, the different domains (mydomain.com , mydomain.de , mydomain.fr ) share the same site and the same files.

Everything works fine, and the user who goes on mydomain.com find the very same content of the user who goes to mydomain.de

But for few .php files I need to change contents, according to the domain used by the user to connect to the site; which is to say, i.e., the user coming from mydomain.com will have different contents from the user coming from mydomain.fr

And the question is: how can I understand in php which domain is in use from that user? Does exist any variable or function which can help in understanding if a certain user is coming from mydomain.com or mydomain.fr ?

Answer (score 1):

Just examine the `Host` header, that is exactly what Apache does to determine the host.

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.